# Allow adding multiple values Manually in Choice field Power apps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I try to edit my field to allow the user to add multiple values manually by the following script but still it's only allow one value:

1- edit card "Update" property,

```
If(
    !IsBlank(cmbPickSomething.Selected),
    cmbPickSomething.Selected,
    If(
        !IsBlank(cmbPickSomething.SearchText),
        {
            Value: cmbPickSomething.SearchText,
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference"
        },
        Blank()
    )
)
```

2- Allow the following in Column settings:
"Can add values manually" & "Allow multiple selections"

Comment: You looking at the code you provided, you are only passing the single value conditionally. You are either passing the cmbPickSomething.Selected or cmbPickSomething.SearchText or Blank().

Comment: @GaneshSanap so what's your suggestions to allow adding multiple values manually?

Comment: Are you using SubmitForm() for adding/updating records in the list? It would have been easier with the Patch function by creating a single collection with search text and combobox selected values and passing it to column within Patch function.

Comment: You can try collecting the values in collection onchange of combobox control and then pass it to the Update property of datacard.